# Can only read empty Pandas dataframes with Parquet

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm unable to open any Parquet tables unless they're empty, writing appears to work. There is no traceback, nothing returned. Pyarrow 1.0.1, Pandas 1.1.2 on Python 3.8.5 (Win10). Anything obvious I'm missing before a bug report? pyarrow-feather works without issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame([11, 22, 33], columns=['col'])
pout = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(pout, 'example.parquet')

# Alternative
#pout = df.to_parquet('example.parquet')

tab = pq.read_table('example.parquet')
df = tab.to_pandas()

# Alternative
#df = pd.read_parquet('example.parquet')

print(df)
```

Comment: @mikksu Yeah, tried both that's why they're still in the example (commented out).

Answer (score -1):

This code works. I tried this in [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LMAtDlgzUEGwDLnzcNGxZ2iA8Lk8SAjx?usp=sharing).

Comment: As it should since it's the most basic example. Then it's a bug and more curiously does not produce any error at all. The line that fails is read_table.

Comment: You say you cannot open any Parquet table, but you can read and print 'df'. So how do you decide that read_table line fails?

Comment: I cannot print the df, it's present for test purposes. My issue is a bug tracked at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-8385